# Get file time before downloading the file using FTP

Tags: java, ftp

Any way to get the file creation date or last modification date without using getModificationTime in Java.

I'm using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient class. My issue is, I'm unable to use getModificationTime to get the time stamp before downloading the file..

Comment: MDTM is an FTP *command*, so why would you expect it to be listed as an Eclipse suggestion? --- Also, what `getModificationTime` method are you referring to? --- Show the code you currently have and specify which FTP library you're using, if any.

Comment: I'm trying to get the last modification date of the file I'm trying to FTP without downloading it into the local

Comment: So???? *How*? What FTP class are you using? What FTP library? Or are you asking for a library with such functionality? If so, then let me quite the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): ***Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow***.

Comment: I'm using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient class.  
My issue is, I'm unable to use getModificationTime to get the time stamp before downloading the file

Comment: Don't you think that information is *important* to the question? Don't you think you should **edit** the question to *clarify* it? Please read the following [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) article: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Only you ask a good question, you might get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library, here is a sample code:

```
package com.grebski.ftp;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FtpTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String ftpUrl = "speedtest.tele2.net";
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(ftpUrl);
        ftpClient.user("anonymous");
        ftpClient.pass("anonymous@a.com");
        Arrays.stream(ftpClient.listFiles()).forEach(file -> {
                    LocalDateTime creationDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(file.getTimestamp().getTimeInMillis()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
                    String msg = String.format("%s %s", file.getName(), creationDateTime);
                    System.out.println(msg);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "The method stream(FTPFile[]) is undefined for the type Arrays". What could be the traditional way of getting modified time stamp?

Comment: How can we get the same in Java 7?

Comment: The whole Arrays.stream line can be removed, what u should be interested in is `ftpClient.listFiles()` which returns array of files on ftp server, you can iterate through the array then

Answer (score -1):

Did you get a chance to find the size of the file and the network speed? They are important aspects to learn the download time.

Comment: Not an answer. Should be a comment, so just wait until you have the 50 rep needed. You're almost there. Delete this answer to clear the negative rep I just gave you by down-voting.

Comment: I'm trying to get the last modification date of the file I'm trying to FTP without downloading it into the local